# Angular directive calling querySelectorAll is using 5% cpu

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have this angular directive that removes all image div containers if there is no images in the whole section.

```
myApp.directive('imageContainerRemoval', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var watchGroup = attrs.imageContainerRemoval,
          sectionGotImage = false;

      // 0 milisec delay to ensure ng-style is applied and ng-repeat has finished.
      setTimeout(function() {

        var elementsInClass = $('[image-container-removal="' + watchGroup + '"]');

        // Check for images in section.
        if ($(elementsInClass).children().length > 0) {
          sectionGotImage = true;
        }

        // If there's no images in section, delete all image container divs.
        if (!sectionGotImage) {
          $(elementsInClass).remove();
          sectionGotImage = false;
        }
      }, 0);
    }
  };
});
```

From debugging in chrome browser i noticed that `querySelectorAll` takes up 5.27% and out of that 4.49% goes to my `image-container-removal` directive

`var elementsInClass = $('[image-container-removal="' + watchGroup + '"]');`

I'm pretty clueless to why this call is so expensive since I'm using it in similar fashion in another directive as well and that call is below 0.5%

**from chrome debugger profile**

[image]

Comment: I highly recommend reading up on some of angulars principles. You have a lot of jquery code in here and are also using setTimeout. My suggestion would be to create a directive for the things you're searching and wire into them that way.

Comment: You are using a attribute selector which is a very costly one... you need to narrow your search using other selectors like element selector or descendant selector

Comment: If you want to look inside only the `imageContainerRemoval` directive then you can use `var elementsInClass = element.find('[image-container-removal="' + watchGroup + '"]');`, if you also know if it will always be `div` elements then `var elementsInClass = element.find('div[image-container-removal="' + watchGroup + '"]');`

Comment: Also how many times the directive's link function is getting called

Comment: @ArunPJohny every image added - which in the example is 128

Comment: @AndersPedersen you need to fine tune the selector, checkout the above example I shared

Comment: cheers, ill look into it.

Comment: Also, you should use $timeout at the very least, but it's a code smell... As of 1.5, investigate the use of $onInit in a controller...

Comment: Also, using jQuery to remove elements having Angular directives may cause leaks, as the directives and scopes may not be destroyed properly.

Comment: @ArunPJohny went from 4.4% to 0.03% :)

Comment: Looking at your code, you could replace it with an `ngIf`...

Comment: @AndersPedersen now that is something :)

Comment: @malix as stated above, its only if  **ALL** the divs are empty - lets say there is a section of 5 - 1 of those has an image, then all the containers are **NOT** be deleted for alignment reasons. so i highly doubt ng if can be used for this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the selector you are using.

You are using a attribute equals selector, which is a very poor selector in terms of performance. You need to use it always together with other selectors as as descendant selector or with class/id selector etc

If you want to look inside only the `imageContainerRemoval` directive then you can use

```
var elementsInClass = element.find('[image-container-removal="' + watchGroup + '"]');
```

If you also know if it will always be div elements then

```
var elementsInClass = element.find('div[image-container-removal="' + watchGroup + '"]');
```